# Automatic card resizing as the window go smaller

Tags: html, css

I am trying to build a cards and stuck at one point.

I want to get the images go smaller relatively as the window size go smaller.

Objective: Pics size go smaller where I can see all 3 images till 600px while they remain at centre till 600px.

And I wrote a media query to get only one image below 600px but cant get the image go relatively smaller when I reduce window size.

Image container should should go smaller but I got stuck.

Any guidance would be helpful?

```css
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.h1{
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}

.card-continer{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 10px;
}

/* .card{
    width: 400px;
    height: 380px;
    position: relative;

} */

.card .card-image{
    width: 400px;
    height: 380px;
    position: relative;
}

.card:nth-child(1) .card-image{
    background-image: url("https://transcode-v2.app.engoo.com/image/fetch/f_auto,c_lfill,h_128,dpr_3/https://assets.app.engoo.com/images/1ejRYY8i2K7I3VAtaJKbWm.jpeg");

}

.card:nth-child(2) .card-image{
    background-image: url("https://transcode-v2.app.engoo.com/image/fetch/f_auto,c_lfill,h_128,dpr_3/https://assets.app.engoo.com/images/1ejRYY8i2K7I3VAtaJKbWm.jpeg");
    
}

.card:nth-child(3) .card-image{
    background-image: url("https://transcode-v2.app.engoo.com/image/fetch/f_auto,c_lfill,h_128,dpr_3/https://assets.app.engoo.com/images/1ejRYY8i2K7I3VAtaJKbWm.jpeg");
    
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .h1{
        text-align: center;
        position: relative;
    }
    
    .card-continer{
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        gap: 10px;
    }
    
    /* .card{
        width: 400px;
        height: 380px;
        position: relative;
    
    } */
    
    .card .card-image{
        width: 400px;
        height: 380px;
        position: relative;
    }
    
    .card:nth-child(1) .card-image{
        background-image: url("https://transcode-v2.app.engoo.com/image/fetch/f_auto,c_lfill,h_128,dpr_3/https://assets.app.engoo.com/images/1ejRYY8i2K7I3VAtaJKbWm.jpeg");
        position: relative;
    }
    
    .card:nth-child(2) .card-image{
        background-image: url("https://transcode-v2.app.engoo.com/image/fetch/f_auto,c_lfill,h_128,dpr_3/https://assets.app.engoo.com/images/1ejRYY8i2K7I3VAtaJKbWm.jpeg");
        display: none;
    }
    
    .card:nth-child(3) .card-image{
        background-image: url("https://transcode-v2.app.engoo.com/image/fetch/f_auto,c_lfill,h_128,dpr_3/https://assets.app.engoo.com/images/1ejRYY8i2K7I3VAtaJKbWm.jpeg");
        display: none;
    }
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <title>trail2</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="h1">
        <h1>Responsive Cards</h1>
    </div>
    

    <div class="card-continer">

        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-image">

            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-image">
                
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-image">
                
            </div>
        </div>


    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try using a combination of `width` and `max-width`... for instance `width:100%;max-width:400px`... then when the available width the element is in is more than 400px it will be 400px... otherwise it will be 100% of the available (smaller) area

Answer (score 0):

grid would be a better solution in this case. Because you use background images inside div, so you need to set a width and a height. It's not good for responsive.
But with grid you can use fraction to divide your container in 3 columns with the same size. And the fraction will be responsive depends on your screen size.
I made a example with your code

Comment: here is the link to the code : https://codepen.io/0r-et-0/pen/wvmRKjj