# How can I resize an image dynamically with CSS as the window width/height changes?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to resize the images along with the container they are in when I resize the window.

Either they are stuck without moving or they go into column when the window size is reduced.
How to do resizing when the window size goes down all 3 images sizes go down along with it in relative to the window size once it hit a certain window size, where I can see all 3 images but the size goes down with window size?

```html
<body>
    <div class="h1">
        <h1>Responsive Cards</h1>
  </div>
    <div class="card-continer">
        <div class="card">
            <img src="https://transcode-v2.app.engoo.com/image/fetch/f_auto,c_lfill,h_128,dpr_3/https://assets.app.engoo.com/images/1ejRYY8i2K7I3VAtaJKbWm.jpeg">
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <img src="https://transcode-v2.app.engoo.com/image/fetch/f_auto,c_lfill,h_128,dpr_3/https://assets.app.engoo.com/images/1ejRYY8i2K7I3VAtaJKbWm.jpeg">
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <img src="https://transcode-v2.app.engoo.com/image/fetch/f_auto,c_lfill,h_128,dpr_3/https://assets.app.engoo.com/images/1ejRYY8i2K7I3VAtaJKbWm.jpeg">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: you have a css selector `.car` but no car class in your HTML. Maybe you meant `.card` ?

Comment: @cloned sorry , just a typing mistake , fixed now

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Automatic card resizing as the window go smaller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73389722/automatic-card-resizing-as-the-window-go-smaller)

Comment: @Anton since it didnt workout , i tried in another way and yes still stuck

Comment: Use your browser's dev tools inspect facility to see exactly who/where is reformatting e.g. into a column. Also, please make your code into a runnable snippet which shows the problem. As it stands everything is columnar whatever the viewport width.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code:

```
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.h1{
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}

.card-continer{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:row;
    align-items:center;
    justify-content:center;
    padding:0;
}


img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
.card {
    height: 200%;
    width: 200px;
}
```

[image]

It's working.

Comment: thanks , I know this way and tried but its not working everywhere

Comment: What not working everywhere means..? @Learn-code

Comment: I try to put into the main website that I am building and when i reduce the size the images go column after certain size instead of reducing the size with the above method

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73389722/automatic-card-resizing-as-the-window-go-smaller

Comment: the above link is another way that i tried but faced the same problem

Comment: Also you can check this [link](https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/css/how-to-auto-resize-an-image-to-fit-an-html-container.html) @Learn-code